# Measure HeartRate at specific Event

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am writing a Running-Workout-App for my Apple Watch and after 1km the app measures the HeartRate and compares it to a specific value. Afterwards, an Alert will displayed, if the Heartrate is to high.

**My Question:**

- Is it possible to measure the Heart Rate at a specific point in my
  application and compare it to a specific value?
- Is that possible
  without Streaming the HeartRate from Healthkit?

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the distance updates and use an [HKSampleQuery](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hksamplequery) to get the last heart rate measurement when the user reaches 1KM.

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
let heartrate = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)
let sort = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
]
let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")

let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartrate!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: sort, resultsHandler: {
    query, results, error in
    if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample]
    {
        let sample = results[0] as HKQuantitySample
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
        print (value)

        let rate = results[0]
        print(rate)
    }
})

healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
```